# How to use completely custom GUI-Elements for customize OS design

Tags: java, python, c++, user-interface, custom-controls

the mainproject is to customize Windows-OS that it looks like OS X or Mac OS. The question is: How to create completely own Windows, Frames etc. and especially custom GUI widgets? The GUI should get drawn without the Windows API because i want to redesign the complete window, it's frame and borders etc.

Is their any way to do something like that? Maybe with a own new Engine that draws the GUI with it's own methods?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done but it is by no means easy, Plenty of frameworks already do so (implementing UI from scratch, not necessarily your particular desired look and feel). WPF and QT for instance do not rely on the API for any of their UI look (they do, of course, rely on the API for the actual drawing, there is no way around that).

You will need to implement control placement management, drawing, hit-testing and all the other usual operations that the API normally takes care of for you.